# Why is self-hosted gitlab runner having trouble cloning repo and executing the job on self-hosted runner

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm currently playing around with GitLab runners to better understand how they work in the context of a CI/CD pipeline. I followed the instructions in the GitLab docs for creating a self-managed runner (i.e. my personal Windows laptop):

- Installed the GitLab Runner executable
- registered my runner with GitLab
- disabled shared runners for my toy project
- modified `toml` file to use `powershell` as shell executor instead of `pwsh`

After going through these steps, I created a CI/CD pipeline using the GitLab web UI. The default `.gitlab-ci.yml` file generated looks like this:

```
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build-job:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code..."
    - echo "Compile complete."

unit-test-job:   # This job runs in the test stage.
  stage: test    # It only starts when the job in the build stage completes successfully.
  script:
    - echo "Running unit tests... This will take about 60 seconds."
    - sleep 60
    - echo "Code coverage is 90%"

lint-test-job:   # This job also runs in the test stage.
  stage: test    # It can run at the same time as unit-test-job (in parallel).
  script:
    - echo "Linting code... This will take about 10 seconds."
    - sleep 10
    - echo "No lint issues found."

deploy-job:      # This job runs in the deploy stage.
  stage: deploy  # It only runs when *both* jobs in the test stage complete successfully.
  script:
    - echo "Deploying application..."
    - echo "Application successfully deployed."
```

Basically just `echo` and `sleep` statements. Nothing Powershell can't handle.

However when I manually trigger the pipeline using GitLab's web UI, it lags on `build-job` as follows:

[image]

Finally, it times out as shown below:

[image]

I don't have anything in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file asking the Runner to clone anything from the repo. Why is it trying to clone the repo anyway? Why is it stuck on this step?

## Edit

Extracting the runner logs as indicated by the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html#get-runner-logs) using `get-winevent` indicated the following problem:

```
WARNING: Checking for jobs... failed                
runner=WazTRLts status=couldn't execute POST against https://gitlab.com/api/v4/jobs/request: Post https://gitlab.com/api/v4/jobs/request: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Maybe this helps understand why the timeout occurs? How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is part of any [runner (self-managed or not) workflow](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/#runner-execution-flow)

[image: Runner workflow]

The idea is for your commands (any command) to operate on your code base, which is cloned first.

---

Regarding the timeout and the error, see "[Self-signed certificates or custom Certification Authorities all tiers](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/tls-self-signed.html)"

> For connections to the GitLab server: the certificate file can be specified as detailed in the [Supported options for self-signed certificates targeting the GitLab server section](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/tls-self-signed.html#supported-options-for-self-signed-certificates-targeting-the-gitlab-server).
>
> This solves the `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` problem when registering a runner.

Comment: I see. Would you mind also addressing the second part of my question? Namely why it might have trouble cloning the repo?

Comment: @user32882 I missed that part. You mean your steps are not executed? For testing, can you try with only one step, one command?

Comment: it apparently never reaches the part where it starts to execute the steps. Under `build-job` the runner lags. Please see the image added to the original question...

Comment: I was able to extract some logs using `get-winevent` (Please see edit original question). It looks like the runner has trouble POSTing jobs to GitLab due to certification issues...

Comment: @user32882 Sorry for the delay, I was outside. I have edited the answer to address your error message.

Comment: No worries. I actually found that page and tried setting `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY` to `"true"` in order to disable SSL verification. I don't get that x509 error anymore but it looks like my pipeline still lags. Furthermore disabling SSL verification is a security risk. The documentation provides no indication of where I could find the `--tls-ca-file` or how I can potentially generate it...

Comment: It looks like there was an issue with my connection. I was using a public WIFI (Starbucks). I went to another coffee shop with different wifi and my pipelines work including with SSL verification. So I guess Starbucks is the problem? I thought only their coffee sucked but apparently so does their WIFI.