# Windows gitlab runner stop execute job

Tags: amazon-ec2, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

ci, and i-ve installed my gitlab-runner on a ec2 machine Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS t2.micro, and when im pushing my code to start the build i get this

[image]

But it keeps stucked like this and after 1 hour it timeouts

[image]

I really don't know what to do about this problem knowing that i can clone successfully the project manually in my ec2 machine.

Any help is much appreciated if you ever encountered this problem and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your job config or your timeout

Comment: maybe this help u https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70529254/why-is-self-hosted-gitlab-runner-having-trouble-cloning-repo-and-executing-the-j?rq=1